# "action" and "activity" not the same?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, vocabulary

Since both **'action'**  and **'activity'**  are nouns derived from the verb **act**, I used to think they were interchangeable.

But turns out they are not from this sentence "***.......the activities and actions companies take to......***" , I get a feeling that they mean different things.

Well my question is what is the difference. Thank you.

Comment: Differences in meaning are often dependent on context. It might be very difficult to explain the difference when you've given us so little of the original sentence. [ELL questions are not a good place to be stingy on context](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: The noun _activity_ is used incorrectly here; a subject "takes an action" and "_undertakes_ an activity." It is unreasonable to expect good grammar and correct usage from a marketing company's "sell sheets," especially when the site belongs to a Thai company!

Comment: @J.R.- The whole sentence is "**Customer retention refers to the activities and actions companies take to reduce customer defection.**" I do not think this particular case is dependent  on context thogh.

Comment: @P.E.Dant : I do not get the Thai reference.   :/.

Comment: The site "kyklo.co" is hosted in Thailand, the registrant is "fabien@kyklo.asia," and the registrant address is in Bangkok. English is at best a second or third language to the site's maintainers, and the company itself appears to be Thai. (More salient, though, is the difference between _action_ and _activity,_ for which please see below!)

Comment: My point is that you need to provide enough information so that we can all reach that same conclusion. After all, the sentence could say "...the activities and actions companies take to prevent security breaches in their IT systems," or, "...the activities and actions companies take to ensure their employees have a memorable holiday party." I'm not convinced I'd answer the question exactly the same way for both of those.

Comment: @J.R. : Ok. I encountered one sentence with both only. But certainly I would like to know more. So could you post an answer/comment to explain the meaning of the two sentences you wrote in your comment?

Comment: The fact that these two words are used in the same sentence does not necessarily indicate the two words have distinct and disjoint meanings. Sometimes synonyms are used for reinforcement or emphasis (e.g., *"We have faced many **trials and tribulations** over the past decade"*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> an activity

is an on-going process over a period of time, where as

> an action

is a single event or effort.

> Many *actions* when grouped together form an *activity*.